# Retrieve record azure (swift)

Tags: swift, azure

i know that Azure there's insert, read, update and delete. I having trouble in retrieving in the records in particular table. As this code shown below i'm able to read it. Is there a way where i can use the name and password for login?

I do need to have parameter and make a login as well a session.

func retrieve()
    {

```
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let client = delegate.client!
    let table = client.table(withName: "tablename")
    table.read{ (result, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("ERROR ", err)
        } else if let items = result?.items {
            for item in items {
                print("name ", item["name"]!, "password: ", item["password"]!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```